# How to Monitor/listen aws Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Suppose multiple aws services are running (like EC2,S3) and If someone changes the configuration of these services , I want to know immediately and want to pull the updated configuration. So how can i listen to these services to pull configuration immediately . I went through couple of options like aws SNS and all. But i don't want to implement this using any aws services for this.
I am using spring boot application. Any help is appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at AWS Config?

Comment: @Marcin AWS Config internally send the notification to SNS and As i said I don't want to use the AWS services.

Answer (score 0):

The two services you should be interested in are:

[AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html):

> AWS CloudTrail is an AWS service that helps you enable governance, compliance, and operational and risk auditing of your AWS account. Actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service are recorded as events in CloudTrail. Events include actions taken in the AWS Management Console, AWS Command Line Interface, and AWS SDKs and APIs.

[AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html):

> AWS Config provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.

You can also configure **Amazon CloudWatch Events rules** that trigger when a particular API call is made (eg when a user changes some configuration). This could trigger a notification, a Lambda function, etc.

See:

- [Creating a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on an AWS API Call Using AWS CloudTrail - Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html)
- [How to monitor AWS account activity with Cloudtrail, Cloudwatch Events and Serverless](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-cloudtrail-cloudwatch-events/)